# Supervisor and Shell command discrepancy: export variable from file working for in supervisor but not in shell, why?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables, supervisord

suppose there's a file into `/tmp/confs.sh`, that looks like:

```
export CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT="//var/www"
```

and it's used inside a `supervisor` configuration file like this:

```
[program:laravel-horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=/bin/bash -c ". /tmp/confs.sh && /usr/local/bin/php ${CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT}/artisan horizon"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
user=myUser
```

I though my supervisor configuration didn't work with the variable but I was wrong. Before I discovered this I made tests in my shell and they really didn't work with the variable. The test is:

```
$ /bin/bash -c ". /tmp/confs.sh && printenv &&  echo ${CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT}/artisan"
```

and the output is

```
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
USER=logotel
PWD=/home/logotel
HOME=/home/logotel
CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT=//var/www
MAIL=/var/mail/logotel
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=2
LOGNAME=logotel
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
_=/usr/bin/printenv
/artisan
```

this means that `printenv` works as aspected (I see the row `CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT=//var/www`), but the last line (wich is the output of `echo ${CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT}/artisan`), seems doesn't detect the exported variable `CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT`.

Why didn't they work while the same command in the supervisor configuration turned out to be fine?

Thanks,
Sim

Comment: Sorry, you are right... effectively there was an error in previous script that badly generates the `/tmp/confs.sh` file, so this is solved. But I'm curious about why my  test `/bin/bash -c ". /tmp/confs.sh && printenv &&  echo ${CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT}/artisan"`, with the right `/tmp/confs.sh` file, fails... so I'd really appreciate if you can explain...

Answer (score 0):

First about your tests. When you run

```
/bin/bash -c ". /tmp/confs.sh && printenv &&  echo ${CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT}/artisan"
```

in a shell, your current shell substitutes `${CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT}` because you used double-quotes. Variables in double quotes are substituted with their values. The variable is not set in the current shell, so it gets substituted with an empty string. In effect there is no `${CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT}` substring in what the spawned `bash` gets.

If you do (still in a shell)

```
/bin/bash -c '. /tmp/confs.sh && printenv && echo ${CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT}/artisan'
```

then the spawned `bash` will get the literal string containing `${CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT}`. It will be responsible for substituting the variable.

Note in general [you should double-quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) the variable in the context of the spawned shell, so the command should rather be

```
/bin/bash -c '. /tmp/confs.sh && /usr/local/bin/php "${CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT}/artisan" horizon'
```

---

Then there is `supervisord` which does not parse commands given after `command=` as a shell would; in particular it doesn't expand variables in a form `$foo` at all. My tests indicate your original line

> ```
> command=/bin/bash -c ". /tmp/confs.sh && /usr/local/bin/php ${CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT}/artisan horizon"
> ```

should indeed work in this case. Note the variable in the context of the spawned shell is not quoted. We cannot use single-quotes as outer ones because `supervisord` only supports double-quotes to group arguments with spaces in them to pass to the program. We cannot use sole single-quotes as inner ones because variables in single-quotes don't get expanded.

According to my tests the parser of `supervisord` supports escaping double-quote characters with `\`. This should work for you *and* be more robust:

```
command=/bin/bash -c ". /tmp/confs.sh && /usr/local/bin/php \"${CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT}/artisan\" horizon"
```

To be clear: it's just a slight improvement, a good practice in shell scripting (that doesn't really matter in your particular case of `//var/www` but it may matter in general); aside from that your original line was fine.

The discrepancy was because in your shell the substring `${CONTAINER_CODE_PROJECT_ROOT}` in double-quotes was expanded before `bash -c` even run. In supervisor such expansion doesn't occur; double-quotes after `command=` are more like single-quotes in a shell.

Comment: the double quotes... doh!!! how did I not think about it ... I really feel like a noob! 
your explanation was perfect and very welcome, thank you very much!